# Docusign Connect API set the envelope on Queue but the retryCount don't change

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the [ConnectEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/) Api's.

Specifically the following api's

- [retryForEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/retryForEnvelope/)

  > Republishes Connect information for the specified envelope.
- [retryForEnvelopes](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/retryForEnvelopes/)

  > Republishes Connect information for the specified set of envelopes. The primary use is to republish Connect post failures by including envelope IDs for the envelopes that failed to post in the request. The list of envelope IDs that failed to post correctly can be retrieved by calling to [ML:GetConnectLog] retrieve the failure log.

I get this JSON response

```
{
 "retryQueue": [
    {
     "envelopeId": "aaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeee",
     "configId": "Envelope",
     "configUrl": "",
     "status": "Queued",
     "statusMessage": ""
   }
 ]
}
```

The response show me that the webhook is on queue but if i try to call - [listFailures](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/listFailures/)
I can see that the `retryCount` property is still 0

Something can i be missing?

Additional Notes:

-If i go to the connect console on the admin page and i click the `Republish` button from the UI console, the value is still 0

-I am testing with a demo account, not sure if there is any policy of the retry endpoint on demo.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you wait a couple of minutes, does the message still show as queued?
Also, if you click "republish" from the web console does the notification get re-published to your listener? You also may need to wait a minute or two. Then refresh the page. The fact that you're using a Demo account is not the issue.